# Holes in wood furniture: identifying the cause

Tags: furniture, pest-control, insect

About one year ago, we settled in a new house in south west France. We also bought a new wood table (made of reused wood from older furnitures).

I heard a bit of noise in the room last night while sitting close to the table. I thought of termites but eventually I blamed it on the cat. Today, I discovered two holes on that table, about 3 mm large (see pics below), and two others under the table

From a quick internet search, my guess is [common furniture beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_furniture_beetle) but I may very well be wrong.

From what I gathered, it takes years from the egg being laid to the adult breaking through the surface, so my understanding is that the beetle or whatever it is must have been there already when we bought the table.

[image: Large]
[image: Close]
[image: Very close]
[image: Hole only]

Termites have been spotted in the backyard far from the house (say 20 m). Although it is a long time concern, I don't think it is relevant here. Also, I've been using wood in the wood stove that had holes as well but much smaller and I wouldn't let the wood stay too long in the house before burning it so I don't think it is related either.

The house is made of bricks with drywall, wooden floors all over the place and of course we have other wood furnitures.

While I'm interested in the risks and what we should do, this might be too broad for the scope of the question and I'll probably reach out to a professional.

**I would like to get a confirmation that my assumptions above are correct and the beettle was in the wood when we bought the table.** This would make the seller responsible for this, if not legally, at least "physically". In fact, it might even fall in the 2-year warranty of the table.

**Edit**

A third hole appeared and I manage to capture the insect with a glass before it flies away.

[image: Insect]

I couldn't identify it, though.

I also called customer service and we should get a replacement table.

**Edit 2**

The insect was identified in https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/104382/identify-bug-found-eating-wood-table.

I argued that we bought the table recently so the insects must have been there before and I got a replacement.

The two replacement tables we were proposed were far less beautiful (they are made of reused wood so they vary in quality) so we kept the one we had. We havent't seen any new hole since then so we assume the insects are gone.

Comment: you cannot get any confimation from the internet ... you can only get guesses ... the table would have to be examined by a qualified person

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: spray for bugs, asap.

Comment: Did you see any evidence that the holes really are new, like sawdust-ish remnants near the holes or on the floor under the table?

Comment: Some people add those holes to new furniture so it looks authentic.  https://www.colonialpest.com/man-made-worm-holes-in-furniture/

Comment: @jsotola, sorry for the long text. The question is is bold: I'd like a confirmation the the bugs must have been there before. Any other comment or suggestion welcome. I'll contact a qualified person.

Comment: @brhans while moving the table to look under it, I did see sawdust on the edge of the hole. Besides I know they are new as I would have seen them before, for sure.

Comment: @Willk: I didn't do those holes myself, of course, and they were not there when I bought the table. It has been a year, I would have noticed.

Comment: I think it is caused by the beetle rather than the termite. I had a similar situation in my house. While I moved in, I noticed small holes in many locations on the wood floor, then found one solution - "Boric Acid Powder". I spread the power at the holes and nearby areas. After that, I didn't see the number of holes increasing. Give it a try.

Comment: No, not common furniture beetle the holes are too big.

Comment: @Jasen, I manage to capture the culprit and added a picture to the question.

Comment: You had it right the first time. It was the cat. He has a very tiny drill and he hates you.

Comment: Not as much as I hate him.